# Why do I get a warning when specifying the recipient for signing a document?

Tags: gnupg, openpgp, yubikey

I just got a Yubikey 4 and I generate the key with `gpg2 --card-edit` and now I have this:

```
$ gpg2 --list-key
/home/lilas/.gnupg/pubring.kbx
------------------------------
pub   rsa2048/EA3829E3 2016-11-08 [SC]
uid         [ultimate] Yubikey Test <yubikey@test.org>
sub   rsa2048/47C539AE 2016-11-08 [A]
sub   rsa2048/AC969F81 2016-11-08 [E]
```

If I don't specify the recipient, evething works fine, but if I specify it it show me the warning

> gpg: WARNING: recipients (-r) given without using public key encryption

```
$ gpg2  --sign /tmp/test

$ gpg2 --verify /tmp/test.gpg 
gpg: Signature made Tue 08 Nov 2016 02:13:46 PM BRST using RSA key ID EA3829E3
gpg: Good signature from "Yubikey Test <yubikey@test.org>" [ultimate]

$ rm /tmp/test.gpg 

$ gpg2 -r yubikey@test.org --sign /tmp/test
gpg: WARNING: recipients (-r) given without using public key encryption

$ gpg2 --verify /tmp/test.gpg 
gpg: Signature made Tue 08 Nov 2016 02:14:20 PM BRST using RSA key ID EA3829E3
gpg: Good signature from "Yubikey Test <yubikey@test.org>" [ultimate]
```

I just found out that it works as I expected if I use the option `-u` instead of `-r`. What is the difference of using one or another? I feel that I misunderstood the meaning of recipient, could someone clarify this please? And what this warning means?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`--recipient` or the short `-r` is used to denote a recipient, which is something only relevant for *encryption*. GnuPG is warning you that you're not encrypting the messaage.

```
   --recipient name
   -r     Encrypt  for user id name. If this option or --hidden-recipient is not
          specified, GnuPG asks for the user-id unless --default-recipient
          is given.
```

If you want to select the key to sign a message, use `--local-user` or `-u`. For a message that's only signed, but not encrypted, it does not matter who the recipient is.

```
   --local-user name
   -u     Use  name as the key to sign with. Note that this option overrides
          --default-key.
```

This is usually defined in `gpg.conf`.

If you want to both sign and encrypt a message for `yubikey@test.org`, apply both commands (add `--local-user` if necessary):

```
gpg2 --recipient yubikey@test.org --sign --encrypt /tmp/test
```